# Python TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, bluetooth

```
import bluetooth
import time

class btHandler():

    hostMACAddress = '98:D3:31:30:45:80'
    port = 1
    gyro = [None]
    rot = [None]
    data = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.clientSocket = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
        self.clientSocket.connect((self.hostMACAddress, self.port))
        self.clientSocket.setblocking(True)

    def testRead(self):
        self.gyro = [None] * 3
        global data
        d = self.clientSocket.recv(1)
        d = ord(d[0])
        if d == 0x25:
            d = self.clientSocket.recv(1)
            d = ord(d[0])
            if d == 0x72:
                time.sleep(0.02)
                self.data = self.clientSocket.recv(28)
            if len(self.data)<28:
                print "Wrong data lenght", len(self.data)
            else:
                self.gyro[0] = ord(self.data[0]) * 256 + ord(self.data[1])
                print self.gyro[0]
                return self.gyro[0]

    def getGyroValues(self):
        self.rot = [None] * 3
        self.rot[0] = ord(self.data[10]) * 256 + ord(self.data[11])
        print rot[1];
```

This is my code and I'm getting error at line 37 (self.rot[0] = ord(self.data[10]) * 256 + ord(self.data[11]) )
What my program do is read data microcontroller using bluetooth.

Comment: `__getitem__` is called when you do indexing, like you are doing on that line (`self.data[10]` and `self.data[11]`). You have a bug in your code where `self.data` is being set to an integer, but clearly you are expecting it to be a list or tuple or some kind of collection.

Comment: I don't know python very well, but the error says that `self.data` is not an array-like type although you try to access it like one there.

Comment: Because we don't see the code where this module is used (where is `getGyroValues` called?) it is difficult to help beyond telling you that `self.data` is an integer when the module expects it to be a list or tuple. I would try debugging to the point right before when `getGyroValues` is called and check what the value of data is at that point, then work backwards from there.

Comment: from btHandler import *

bth=btHandler()

while True:
 bth.getGyroValues()

here i call getGyroValues, it's  another class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__getitem__` is indexing, so check your code to see if you have done an index operation (`[]`) on an int in your code, and fix it.